# Java Listen to application closing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, windowlistener

I am trying to catch the Event related to the application closure.
Unfortunately the WindowListener does not do it. I have put the Listener on the main JFrame.

```
jFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        try {
            FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File("./temp/"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

Why is the windowClosing never called in any case?

---

@khelwood this is the code for the JFrame and its construction in the Application.

```
public class EmeryJFrame extends JFrame {

public EmeryJFrame() throws HeadlessException {
    super();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                Debug.infomess("clean exit");
                try {
                    FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File("./temp/"));
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                e.getWindow().dispose();
                System.exit(0);
                }
        });
}}
```

The main Application:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
      new SVGApplication();
}

public class SVGApplication   {
      protected SVGApplication() {
          jFrame = new EmeryJFrame();
      }
}
```

The issue does not come from the LookAndFeel (tested).
I also removed the 'try catch' for better readability.

Comment: Have you [set the default close operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int)) for the JFrame?

Comment: I did jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); It does not change the result.

Comment: You probably want to use `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` since you are handling the close operation yourself.

Comment: I tried DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE, no reaction from the Listener...

Comment: Could you put the @Override annotation on your windowClosing method to make sure you are correctly overriding the method? (You should always use the `@Override` annotation when overriding.)

Comment: Yes thanks I did, but still not passing thru my Listener :(

Comment: I think you'll have to put together an [mre]. I can't see anything in the code you've posted that accounts for what you're observing.

Comment: Ok I'll do it later today and will insert in a next answer.

Comment: your code works for me.

Comment: The uncompilable code snippets seen above do ***not*** make for a [mre]. Please post code (a **single code block**) that compiles cleanly with no need to add anything (including `import` statements) and runs to demonstrate the stated problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce the issue in a snippet. The project has 35 classes and 45000 lines of code. There is probably something in the project that cancels the WindowListener effect. I will have to dig and when I find the cause I will post the resolution here.

Comment: I found the reason why the WindowListener is disabled. I start a new thread with this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57257529/java-windowclosing-event-not-called

Answer (score 0):

```
jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

jFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
           public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                try {
                    FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File("./temp/"));
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                e.getWindow().dispose();
                System.exit(0);
           }
        });
```

Comment: I did jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); It does not change the result.