# Java WindowClosing event not called when jFrame.setUndecorated(true) is set

Tags: java, swing, jframe, windowlistener

In the following snippet the WindowClosing event is not called except if you remove one line of code to the snippet.
The line of code to be removed is:

```
jFrame.setUndecorated(true);
```

Apparently this setUndecorated(true) method disables the WindowListener/WindowAdapter functionality. Is this normal?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class WindowClosing extends JFrame {

    private static WindowClosing jFrame;
    private static Container contentPane;

    public WindowClosing() throws HeadlessException {
        super();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "closing" ,"Cookie", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    try {
                        FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File("./temp/"));
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    e.getWindow().dispose();
                    System.exit(0);
                    }
            });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        jFrame = new WindowClosing();
        jFrame.setUndecorated(true);
        jFrame.pack();
        contentPane = jFrame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Combined with DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE I guess. You seem to have found a specific behaviour. Also look into **`File.deleteOnExit`**.

Comment: If I remove DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE or replace by DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE the problem is still the same. The issue comes from this jFrame.setUndecorated(true) command. Of course with jFrame.setUndecorated(false) the issue disappears.

Comment: I think I vaguely remember now (>10 years ago), `windowClosing` is still before the real closing, assuming a close icon pressed. `windowClosed` must be used.

Comment: What about closing the application with a menu item, which is the case here when setUndecorated is set to true?

Comment: The issue here is not the cleanDirectory action, in my application when the window is closing I have a lot of things to do (saving data) and so on.. So I must trap the window closing. Is there another way?

Comment: `windowClosed`?

Comment: Same as WindowClosing.

Comment: With DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE for the main frame. But I remember I did it differently...

Comment: In fact it is not the setUndecorated method that is the issue. This method forces the closure of the window by menu item (ie). As Joop Eggen said, the windowListener is called when clicking the Icon on the corner of the window, it is not called if the application is closed with a menu item. BUT WHY ??

Answer (score 0):

The reason WindowListener is not called when closing the frame is due to:
the window is not closed with the closing icon of the frame, which are disabled by `jFrame.setUndecorated(true);`.
Even if the system icons (close, maximize, minimize) are present and the user close the frame with a menu item, the WindowListener is not called.